# Using local-storage to change text in button and panel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, local-storage

I have this code in my file: (I omitted lots of other irrevelant code)

```
<div data-role="panel" id="loc_panel"> 
    <h2>Panel Header</h2>
    <p>info about this stop</p>
</div> <!-- /panel -->

<a href="#loc_panel" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-shadow" id="panel_button">Open Panel</a>

<a href="#tt_popup" data-role="button" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn  ui-corner-all" id="button_stop7" data-transition="flip">button_stop6</a>
 <a href="#tt_popup" data-role="button" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn  ui-corner-all" id="button_stop6" data-transition="flip">button_stop7</a>
```

I want to change the text in the panel and the button so you can view information about stop 7 if you click on the button stop 7, and for stop 6 if you click on that button. 
I also want to use local-storage (html5!).

I tried this in a script tag in the head:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function () {
    $("#button_stop6, #button_stop7").on("click", function () {
        $("#tt_popup p").text("Button with ID " + this.id + " was clicked");

        localStorage.setItem('id','this.id');
        var id = localStorage.getItem('id');
        document.write(id);
        document.getElementById("panel_button").value= id;

    });
});
```

When I run it, the page goes to a blank screen with `this.id` written on it. So the part of setting 'this.id' to the localstorage works, but I of course don't want the string `this.id` added to the local storage, I want the id to be set to the local storage.

The value on the panel button doesn't change.

I'm not even close to writing correct javascript, but I'm trying my best to learn!

As you can see the javascript for the panel info is also missing, so like 
     document.getElementById("panel_info").value= "the value corresponding to the id...";
But ... one thing at a time.

Comment: `('id', this.id)` don't wrap it in `''` because it's not a string. Use the same method for panel `$("#panelID h2").text("new text")`. Read more about jquery functions/methods.

Comment: why are you using 'pagecreate' event?

Comment: @ianaya89 he's using jquery mobile (check tags).

Comment: Excuse me, I'm stupid. I was googling for the wrong functions... so that's why I had trouble finding out the syntax. `$("#loc_panel").text("text");` it's just this that doesn't work at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to set the id value in the local storage you should replace this:

`localStorage.setItem('id','this.id');` **by this** `localStorage.setItem('id', this.id);`

Then, I am not sure what you exactly want but you also have an error in this line `document.getElementById("panel_button").value= id;` **replace it by this** `document.getElementById("panel_button").setAttribute('value', id);`

I also noticed that you have this selector `$("#tt_popup p")` but you don't have any html code that match it so you don't have any element to change the text.

Last thing, try to refactor your code you are setting a value on the local storage and then retrieving it and assigning it to new var. I think you can avoid that.

Take a look at [this](http://codepen.io/ianaya89/pen/ayrvh).

Comment: sorry, #tt_popup was only for debugging the first part. doesnt do anything. I notice in your codepen you have the code `document.getElementById("panel_button").setAttribute('value', this.id);` but what does that do? I don't see the panel_button change value, which is what I want. I want the button to show which button was clicked, and I know that sounds very weird. I'm having trouble right now changing text of some html thing, like a button, the way that last jquery line should work.

Comment: PS the way the loc_panel changes is exactly how I wanted it! hmmmm. hang on. if I can do that, I can do a button too

Comment: Nevermind, I think my question is solved now. I'm 100% confused now but I think it works!

Comment: So you want that instead of open modal the button says which button was clicked? If is correct you should add this  $("#panel_button").text(this.id); (check again the codepen)

Comment: Yeah, I just did that inbetween my last two comments. I have read your thoughts ;) Thanks a lot for your time!